# Cakephp 3: Calling Table functions from Entity is a bad or good idea?

Tags: cakephp, model, entity, cakephp-3.0

When I have some entity and I wanna save, validade or delete. Why do I have to call the Table method? For example:

```
$articlesTable = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$article = $articlesTable->get(12);

$article->title = 'CakePHP is THE best PHP framework!';
$articlesTable->save($article);
```

Why isn't like this:

```
$article->save();
```

or `$article->delete();`

It's very simple to implement:

On my Article Entity I can do it like:

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class Article extends Entity
{

    public function save()
    {
        $table = TableRegistry::get($this->source());
        $table->save($this);
    }

}
```

It's working, but I would like to know if its a bad practice or a good idea.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Technically you can do it for the high price of tight coupling (which is considered bad practice).

**Explanation:** I wouldn't consider this best practice because the entity is supposed to be a dumb data object. It should not contain any business logic. Also usually it's not just a simple save call but there is some follow up logic to implement: Handle the success and failure of the save and act accordingly by updating the UI or sending a response. Also you effectively couple the entity with a specific table. You turn a dumb data object into an object that implements business logic.

Technically you can do it this way and I think there are frameworks or ORMs that do it this way but I'm not a fan of coupling things. I prefer to try to write code as lose coupled as possible. [See also SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Also I don't think you'll save any lines of code with your approach, you just move it to a different place. I don't see any benefit that would justify the introduction of coupling the entity to the business logic.

If you go your path I would implement that method as a trait or use a base entity class to inherit from to avoid repeating the code.

Comment: I would like to learn more about this approach. I hadn't considered it before for Table vs. Entity classes in CakePHP and I didn't grasp this intention from the official docs. Is there a deeper discussion on this topic somewhere that you would recommend for reading?

I have been thinking about the distinction in terms of sets vs. individuals. So, methods that deal with sets of entities go on the Table class and methods that only deal with single entities go on the Entity class. But I see that this doesn't really accomplish much other than some trivial code organization.

Comment: Calls to entity setters **don't** delegate to to the table object, nor do getters. Entities are plain dumb data objects. They represent a single row in RDBMS or a document in a document based Storage. The point is not only code organisation but *separation*. The goal is modularity and by this easy maintenance and reuseability. You can build something new out of 10 bricks, if you glue or nail them together you can't, they're coupled and stuck and hard to break apart later. Same applies to software. Suggested read: https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Comment: I understand the separation of concerns principle in the abstract, and I can see how it applies to many other situations, but I was having a hard time applying it with Entities vs. Tables. I think I'm getting it now. Entities are a replacement for the even "dumber" arrays that v2 used, so the role they are coming from was very limited. An Entity need not have come from a Table and nothing requires that it ever be persisted to one. It may never have an `id`, never receive default values that are applied by the Table class during `beforeSave()`, etc.

Comment: As you said, this suggests major limitations on what methods one should place in an Entity. No relational lookups should be placed on Entities, for example, because Entities can easily be in states that make such lookups meaningless. But a common presentation transformation like `$this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name` makes sense on an Entity because it doesn't expect anything it can't fulfill itself.

Comment: You're free to do whatever you want there, but adding business logic there will very likely cause you headache in the long run. The getters and setters a nice places if you immediately need to do something with the data the entity represent. For example I like to add a virtual property "url" and use Router::url() in the getter for that property to return the URL to the related page. This way I don't need to redeclare that route array everywhere I need the URL. If you want to modify collections of entities see https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#map-reduce

Comment: how about using table methods for setting virtual fields based on data from other tables? For example if `users` belong to `groups`, and I want to have a `is_admin` virtual field based on `groups` membership? `_getIsAdmin(){return $table->isAdmin()`}

Comment: @waspinator this is wrong. You put authorization logic into the entity. The authorization logic should be in their own part / library of the application and not coupled with the entity. Pass the entity to the authentication code and let that part do the job. Single responsibility principle. Look it up. Check https://github.com/Phauthentic/authentication & https://github.com/Phauthentic/authorization for decoupled libs. They work with any code / framework.